# Error in my code - Boolean Truth Table

Tags: c++, truthtable

I am currently working on a program that prints a 5 variable truth table. I am using a 2d array. My code currently produces the table, but says it is corrupt and "the stack around the variable "table" was corrupted. Any help?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool table[5][32];

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            table[i][j] = ((i >> j)& 1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            cout << table[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is homework, so I would like to understand it, not just have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The index is wrong. Only `table[0]` to `table[4]` are available, so accessing `table[5]` to `table[31]` is illegal.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool table[32][5]; // swap 32 and 5

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            table[i][j] = ((i >> j)& 1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            cout << table[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So swapping those values just lines it up with the for loops that i have assigning variables and printing?

Comment: Yeah, you were adding to the `i`  variable in the for loop up to 32, but the first array only had 5 cells.

Answer (score 1):

There is attempt to read out of bound values from array.

If you need `5x32` matrix Use code below:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {          // 32-> 5
        for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) {     // 5->32
```

If you need `32x5` matrix then replace code below:

```
    bool table[32][5];        //it was table[5][32];
```